# Azure .NET SDK VirtualMachineSizeType enumeration doesn't list VM size Standard_NC4as_T4_v3 as an option

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sdk, virtual-machine

I am using the Azure .NET SDK in C# to instantiate a VM of size NC4as_T4_v3. The problem that I am running into is that I need to define a VirtualMachineHardwareProfile object with a property VmSize of type VirtualMachineSizeType, but the enumeration VirtualMachineSizeType doesn't list the VM size I want.

Why? And can I define the Hardware Profile differently so as to instantiate this specific size?

A snippet of the code that I would like to use looks like this:

```
VirtualMachineData input = new VirtualMachineData(AzureLocation.EastUS)
{
    HardwareProfile = new VirtualMachineHardwareProfile()
    {
        VmSize = VirtualMachineSizeType.Standard_NC4as_T4_v3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.models.virtualmachinesizetypes?view=azure-python#fields), there is no Virtual Machine of size  `Standard_NC4as_T4_v3` In the **VirtualMachineSizeType** property/Object so it does not list the specified size of VM.

You can use the other fields/sizes to instantiate, which are mentioned in the above document.

Comment: Thats basically what I am stating in my question. The Azure Portal offers more VM sizes than what is encoded in the VirtualMachineSizeType enum. I don't want to use any of the ones in the enum, I want to use Standard_NC4as_T4_v3.

And besides, the link you gave is for the Azure .NET SDK in Python. My code base is in C# as stated.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have chosen to create an ARM template using Bicep. Using the Azure SDK in my C# application to deploy the template to Azure.

This [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-net-management/blob/master/samples/resources/deploy-using-arm-template/Program.cs) gives an example of how to deploy an ARM template using Azure .NET SDK.

By using the Bicep/ARM I am able to define any and all properties of the VM that I want to use.